# PIG - Best way to optimize various grouping structures from one large input

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using Pig to take one big txt file of the form

Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E | Col F | Col G

My goal is to take this input and group by various combinations of the columns to get something like this

(Col A / Col B) |  Count(Col F) | Sum(Col G)

(Col A / Col C) |  Count(Col F) | Sum(Col G)

(Col A / Col D) |  Count(Col F) | Sum(Col G)

(Col B / Col C) |  Count(Col F) | Sum(Col G)

I am wondering if there is way to structure my pig code so that there only has to process the data the minimum number of times as possible since the input stays the same and all that is changing is the grouping.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig does this optimization automatically.  If you always apply the grouping to the original data, all of the grouping can be done in parallel and will be performed in a single map-reduce job.

Given that you want to do the same thing for each grouping, you should define a macro so that you save yourself some typing.  For example:

```
DEFINE DO_STUFF(input, grp1, grp2) RETURNS result {
    grouped = GROUP $input BY ($grp1, $grp2);
    $result = FOREACH grouped GENERATE FLATTEN(group), COUNT(grouped.F), SUM(grouped.G);
};

data = LOAD '/path/to/txt' AS (A, B, C, D, E, F, G:int);
W = DO_STUFF(data, A, B);
X = DO_STUFF(data, A, C);
Y = DO_STUFF(data, A, D);
Z = DO_STUFF(data, B, C);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the information so far and that makes sense but in actuality we are doing different things to different groupings so I guess I wouldn't use a macro. One more thing, the thing is say we have relations W, X ,Y, Z and we need to store each one. If I have separate lines for each store command, will this be not optimal? What I mean by this is for every time i call the command "store" does it have to reload the data, create the groupings and final relations, and then store the data OR does pig know to load the data  once, create the groupings and relations and then hit the stores.

Comment: No, Pig will handle that fine.  If you are typing the commands into the Grunt shell, then every time you enter a `STORE` command, it will perform the entire script to that point.  But if you have your script in a file that you run with Pig, the data will only be loaded once.

Comment: Thank you winnienicklaus, very helpful!